# Using stored procedure to insert many records into database one by one, but it is too slow

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a datagridview containing about 8000 records, and for each record, I call a SQL Server stored procedure to insert it into database, code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_compare.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!DBCommands.sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add(
                CarrierID,
                is_supplier == 1 ? 0 : 1,
                row.Prefix,
                row.RegionName,
                row.NewRate,
                row.FreeBlock,
                row.InitialBlock,
                row.RecycleBlock,
                row.ConnectionCharge,
                row.EnrollDate,
                row.ExpiryDate,
                row.isDisabled,
                row.TimeF1,
                row.TimeT1,
                row.Rate1,
                row.Block1Enabled,
                row.TimeF2,
                row.TimeT2,
                row.Rate2,
                row.Block2Enabled,
                row.TimeF3,
                row.TimeT3,
                row.Rate3,
                row.Block3Enabled,
                Operator,
                FlagShortOverLong,
                ref ErrCode,
                ref ErrMsg))
            {
                //tb_log.Text += DBCommands.LastError + "\r\n";
                MessageBox.Show(DBCommands.LastError);
                return;
            }
}
```

the function `DBCommands.sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add` is this form:

```
public static bool sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add
(
    int CustID,
    int IsInBound,
    string Prefix,
    string RegionName,
    double RatePerMin,
    int FreeBlock,
    int InitialBlock,
    int RecycleBlock,
    double ConnectionCharge,
    DateTime EnrollDate,
    DateTime ExpiryDate,
    int isDisabled,
    TimeSpan TimeF1,
    TimeSpan TimeT1,
    double Rate1,
    int Block1Enabled,
    TimeSpan TimeF2,
    TimeSpan TimeT2,
    double Rate2,
    int Block2Enabled,
    TimeSpan TimeF3,
    TimeSpan TimeT3,
    double Rate3,
    int Block3Enabled,
    string Operator,
    int FlagShortOverLong,
    ref int ErrCode,
    ref string ErrMsg
)
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;

    try
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                LastErrorCode = -1;
                LastError = "Connect database error.";
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LastErrorCode = -1;
            LastError = "Connect database error. " + ex.ToString();
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add_0909", conn);
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = ExecuteTimeout;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@CustID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, CustID);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@IsInBound", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, IsInBound);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Prefix", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60, 30, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, Prefix);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@RegionName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 400, 200, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, RegionName);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@RatePerMin", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13, 20, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, RatePerMin);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@FreeBlock", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, FreeBlock);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@InitialBlock", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, InitialBlock);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@RecycleBlock", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, RecycleBlock);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@ConnectionCharge", SqlDbType.Decimal, 9, 18, 8, ParameterDirection.Input, ConnectionCharge);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@EnrollDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, 23, 3, ParameterDirection.Input, EnrollDate);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@ExpiryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, 23, 3, ParameterDirection.Input, ExpiryDate);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@isDisabled", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, isDisabled);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@TimeF1", SqlDbType.Time, 5, 16, 7, ParameterDirection.Input, TimeF1);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@TimeT1", SqlDbType.Time, 5, 16, 7, ParameterDirection.Input, TimeT1);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Rate1", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13, 20, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, Rate1);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Block1Enabled", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, Block1Enabled);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@TimeF2", SqlDbType.Time, 5, 16, 7, ParameterDirection.Input, TimeF2);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@TimeT2", SqlDbType.Time, 5, 16, 7, ParameterDirection.Input, TimeT2);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Rate2", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13, 20, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, Rate2);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Block2Enabled", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, Block2Enabled);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@TimeF3", SqlDbType.Time, 5, 16, 7, ParameterDirection.Input, TimeF3);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@TimeT3", SqlDbType.Time, 5, 16, 7, ParameterDirection.Input, TimeT3);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Rate3", SqlDbType.Decimal, 13, 20, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, Rate3);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Block3Enabled", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, Block3Enabled);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@Operator", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60, 30, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, Operator);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@FlagShortOverLong", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, FlagShortOverLong);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@ErrCode", SqlDbType.Int, 4, 10, 0, ParameterDirection.Output, null);
            AddParam(sqlCmd, "@ErrMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, 50, 0, ParameterDirection.Output, null);


            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ErrCode = get_int_value(sqlCmd.Parameters["@ErrCode"].Value);
            ErrMsg = get_string_value(sqlCmd.Parameters["@ErrMsg"].Value);

            int _temp = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LastErrorCode = -1;
            LastError = "Execute sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add error. " + ex.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlCmd != null)
            sqlCmd.Dispose();
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

because I need do some check and compare, so I can not save the datagridview to csv and insert the total set of data at once.

In this procedure `sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add_0909`, I do some update and delete, insert operator, although it can work, but it spend too much time

I thought this maybe because the unoptimize update or delete, so I try to change the procedure `sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add_0909`, let it only contain one statement, like this :

```
   select @a=1
```

but it is very strange, the speed of whole procedure seems does not change at all, it still spend much time, can anybody tell me what is the reason?  thanks.

Comment: Look at the `SqlDbType.Structured`.

Comment: Have you used a profiler to see where it's spending all its effort?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what means "too slow" or "too much time"?

Comment: i think its due to the out parameter. Can try  modifiying you sp  and remvoe the two out parameter ?
you can use excute command reader to get any data from sproc.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @Marc_s: with enabled connection-pooling(default) it'll not open/close the physical connection.

Answer (score 2):

> i thought this maybe because the unoptimize update or delete, so i try to change the procedure `sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add_0909` , let it only contain one statement, like this :
>
> ```
> select @a=1
> ```
>
> but it is very strange, **the speed of whole procedure seems does not change at all**, it still spend much time , can anybody tell me what is the reason ? thanks.

Emphasis mine.

This would indicate that your problem is related to latency (alternatively, that the performance of your stored procedure is *not* where the performance problem is; consider looking elsewhere). That is to say, the time to send the request to execute the stored procedure and receive the results is much greater than the time it takes to execute the stored procedure.

Because you call the stored procedure once per record, the time "wasted" due to latency is increased by a factor of 8,000.

You can significantly reduce the number of round-trips by using [table valued parameters](http://mikesdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/inserting-data-into-a-sql-server-database-using-a-table-valued-parameter/) to stream many records to the stored procedure at once.

Note that using table valued parameters isn't a panacea, your stored procedures may suffer poor performance due to parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the stored procedure that's taking too long to execute? Or are you referring to the execution of the entire loop through your DataGridView? Because as far as I can tell you're actually opening and closing 8000 connections to your database which may consume some time itself.

Comment: *Because as far as I can tell you're actually opening and closing 8000 connections to your database which may consume some time itself.* Please Google for *ado .net connection pool*.

Comment: i have not use a profiler to analys because i do not know how to use it, yes i do actually open and close 8000 connections to my database,i know it is stupid,if i only open one connection, how to pass so many record as parameter to store procedure,and for each record , it also need update some other record  before insert into database

Comment: These are some different topics here. First: There is a SQL Server Profiler you can find within the SQL Server Management Studio (might be an optional component though). Second: You don't need to pass all 8000 records to the stored procedure, but you can reuse the same connection for all your procedure calls. And most important, third: Please read @ta.speot.is's answer, as the 8000 round trips to your database server can definitely be a reason for your problems.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you open/close a connection for each call of the stored procedure. if you want to boost the performance, first try to use single connection instead of multiple ones (i.e pass the connection as a parameter to the method and handle the connection externally). something like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")){
  con.Open();

  for (int i = 0; i < dgv_compare.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
     if (!DBCommands.sp_app_RatePlanDetail_Add(
                con,
                CarrierID,
                ...
  };

  con.Close();
}
```

believe this will alleviate the performance problem

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx *This means that during application execution, many identical connections will be repeatedly opened and closed. To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an optimization technique called* connection pooling.

Comment: Yes the connection pool does help a bit, but if you have ever given a try, you would know the difference for 8000 open/close and a single connection (though virtually they are the same) - it seems the overhead is not that minimal.

Comment: i have change code like u told, but it seems do not have a significant speed improve

Comment: yes, that could be the case, like what ta.speot.is said. the second step to optimize it is to look at how to make your single update into batch update, you might want to consider xml or table param. google it for samples

Comment: i had ever experienced a very interesting scenario where I used a transaction to wrap up all the updates/inserts command and it improves the performance by 2 times. but i have no clue why it's like that. probably you want to give a try too